# Enforce usage of VPN-provided DNS servers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, dhcp, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

On a vanilla Ubuntu 18.04 headless server, the OpenVPN client is used to connect to a remote network in tap mode. The address, default gateway, DNS servers etc. are provided by a DHCP server on the remote network.

However, usage of the VPN-provided DNS servers seems to be not enforced. As `systemd-resolved` is used as a stub resolver by default, this is the relevant output of `systemd-resolve --status`:

```
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 16 (tap1)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.0.0.2
          DNS Domain: foo.bar

Link 2 (ens192)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
          DNS Domain: foo2.bar2
```

As you can see, both the DNS servers (from local network DHCP and VPN network DHCP) are present.

- How can I find out which DNS server is actually used by `systemd-resolved`, using command line utilities?
- How can I enforce the usage of the VPN-provided DNS server for all requests? Theoretically, this should be possible by setting the DNS domain to `~.`, as by the `systemd-resolved` documentation. However, with the complex interactions between `systemd-resolved`, `systemd-networkd`, `netplan` and DHCP I was unable to override this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution for my 2nd question:

1. Remove any `netplan` configurations for the tap device, then run `netplan apply`. Netplan configurations always override custom `systemd-networkd` configurations, but they don't provide the necessary options we need.
2. Add a `systemd-networkd` configuration, for instance in `/etc/systemd/network/tap1.network`:

   ```
   [Match]
   Name=tap1

   [Link]
   RequiredForOnline=no

   [Network]
   DHCP=ipv4
   LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
   Domains=~.

   [DHCP]
   UseMTU=true
   RouteMetric=100
   UseDomains=false
   ```
3. Restart the VPN session

Now `systemd-resolved` uses `~.` as the DNS domain as intended. Key elements are the `[Network] Domains=~.` and `[DHCP] UseDomains=false` of the `systemd-networkd` configuration.